# How to get git repo current tag in Dockerfile during automated build in docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have set up an automated build from a Github repository for an application in Docker hub, but as part of the build process, I'd like to be able to write the current tag name to a local file.

Does Docker hub provide any environment variable with the name of the tag being built, which I can `echo` into a local `VERSION` file?

I'd like to avoid actually installing `git` inside the container to perform a `describe`, as well as including the entire (currently dockerignored) `.git` folder to retrieve this info.

Thank you!